# JQuery td inline edit -> after enter go to next edit cell?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, html-table

I am using the code below to insert a edit box, and on enter save the result to MySQL database which is working perfectly

The table cells to edit look like

```
<tr><td class="edit tbl_tracking 92"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="edit tbl_tracking 96"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="edit tbl_tracking 101"></td></tr>
```

After pressing enter and the save is complete I want to automatically select the next edit box with it being focused. So after each entry after pressing enter the next one down is selected and focused. 
There are other cells in each row but have now div or edit required
I cannot work out to to get it working and have looked everywhere

Any help would be great.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('td.edit').click(function () {
            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
            $(this).addClass('ajax');
            $OLDVAL = $(this).text();
            $(this).html('<input id="editbox" size="20" type="text" 
                                    value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
            $('#editbox').focus();
        });

        $('td.edit').keydown(function (event) {
            arr = $(this).attr('class').split(" ");
            if (event.which == 13) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajaxpost.php",
                    data: "value=" + $('.ajax input').val() + "&rownum=" 
                                               + arr[2] + "&field=" + arr[1],
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
                        $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $('#editbox').live('blur', function () {
            $('.ajax').html($('.ajax input').val());
            $('.ajax').html($OLDVAL);
            $('.ajax').removeClass('ajax');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you may try to bind a keydown event to the edit box input. On key down, it should fire the click event of the next cell.

```
$('#editbox').keydown(function(event){
if (event.which == 13)$(this).parent().parent().next().children(':first').trigger('click');
});
```

hope this is helpful

Comment: Thank you - I tried it but it stays on the same line after pushing enter.
I already have this line 
$('td.edit').keydown(function(event){
I tried to integrate it but nothing changes?

Comment: May you exclude any ajax request and include the styles then post your code again? I need a working version of your code. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. If I use the code below it works but does not post to the database. If I put it after the .ajax it doesnt work
    
`code`$(this).parent().next('tr').children('td:nth-child(' + (8) + ')').trigger('click'); return false;`code`

Comment: It says I am limited to how much I can post

This works

$(this).parent().next('tr').children('td:nth-child(' + (8) + ')').trigger('click'); return false;

But if I put it before the .ajax line will not post and after will not work. Thanks for your help

Comment: Worked it out.
Had to include var $obj = $(this);
then
$obj.parent().next('tr').children('td:nth-child(' + (8) + ')').trigger('click'); return false;

All good and working now. Thank you for your help